# Embeddings of forcing notions - preserve properness?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $ M $ be a countable, transitive model for $ \mathsf{ZFC}^* $, i.e. for a sufficiently large finite fragment of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $. Suppose that $ \mathbb{P} := (P, {\leq_P}, \mathbb{1}_P) \in M $ and $ \mathbb{Q} := (Q, {\leq_Q}, \mathbb{1}_Q) \in M $ are forcing notions.

---

### Reminder

**Definition** ([Kun80, VII.7.1]). A mapping $ i \colon P \to Q $ is a *complete embedding* of $ \mathbb{P} $ into $ \mathbb{Q} $ iff

(i) $ \forall r, s \in P \ (r \leq_P s \implies i(r) \leq_Q i(s)) $,

(ii) $ \forall r, s \in P \ (r \perp_P s \implies i(r) \perp_Q i(s)) $, and

(iii) $ \forall q \in Q \ \exists p \in P \ \forall r \in P \ (r \leq_P p \implies i(r) \parallel_Q q) $.

A condition $ p \in P $ as in (iii) is called a *reduction* of $ q $ to $ \mathbb{P} $.

*Remark.* Note that in clause (ii) equivalence holds because of (i).

**Definition** ([Kun80, VII.7.7]). A mapping $ i \colon P \to Q $ is a *dense embedding* of $ \mathbb{P} $ into $ \mathbb{Q} $ iff

(i) $ \forall r, s \in P \ (r \leq_P s \implies i(r) \leq_Q i(s)) $,

(ii) $ \forall r, s \in P \ (r \perp_P s \implies i(r) \perp_Q i(s)) $, and

(iii) $ i[P] $ is dense in $ \mathbb{Q} $.

*Remark.* Every dense embedding is a complete embedding.

**Theorem** ([Kun80, II.3.3]). There exists a dense embedding of $ \mathbb{P} $ into $ \operatorname{RO}(\mathbb{P}) \setminus \{ \mathbb{0} \} $.

**Lemma** ([Kun80, VII.Ex.C2]). If $ \mathbb{P} $ and $ \mathbb{Q} $ are separative and $ i \colon P \to Q $ is a complete embedding of $ \mathbb{P} $ into $ \mathbb{Q} $, then $ i $ is one-to-one, $ i(\mathbb{1}_P) = \mathbb{1}_Q $, and $ (r \leq_P s \iff i(r) \leq_Q i(s)) $ holds for all $ r, s \in P $.

---

Now, consider the following statements:

*(C1)* For each $ \mathbb{Q} $-generic $ H $, there exists a $ G \in M[H] $ such that $ G $ is $ \mathbb{P} $-generic over $ M $. (Then $ M[G] \subseteq M[H] $.)

*(C2)* For each $ \mathbb{P} $-generic $ G $, there exists a $ \mathbb{Q} $-generic $ H $ such that $ G \in M[H] $. (Then $ M[G] \subseteq M[H] $.)

*(C3)* There exists a complete embedding $ i \in M $ of $ \mathbb{P} $ into $ \mathbb{Q} $.

*(C4)* There exists a complete embedding $ i \in M $ of $ \mathbb{P} $ into $ \operatorname{RO}(\mathbb{Q}) \setminus \{ \mathbb{0} \} $.

*(D1)* For each $ \mathbb{Q} $-generic $ H $, there exists a $ G \in M[H] $ such that $ G $ is $ \mathbb{P} $-generic over $ M $ and $ H \in M[G] $. (Then $ M[G] = M[H] $.)

*(D2)* For each $ \mathbb{P} $-generic $ G $, there exists a $ \mathbb{Q} $-generic $ H $ such that $ G \in M[H] $ and $ H \in M[G] $. (Then $ M[G] = M[H] $.)

*(D3)* There exists a dense embedding $ i \in M $ of $ \mathbb{P} $ into $ \mathbb{Q} $.

*(D4)* There exists a dense embedding $ i \in M $ of $ \mathbb{P} $ into $ \operatorname{RO}(\mathbb{Q}) \setminus \{ \mathbb{0} \} $.

*(Pr)* If $ \mathbb{Q} $ is proper, then $ \mathbb{P} $ is also proper.

---

### Question

What implications between the above statements are provable in $ \mathsf{ZFC} $? Which are not?

If it is helpful, you may assume that $ \mathbb{P} $ and $ \mathbb{Q} $ are separative partial orders (in the strict sense).

---

### Main problem

Suppose that *(C1)* holds. What additional assumptions do we need to show *(Pr)*?

(Note that *(C2)* implies *(Pr)*. So what additional assumptions does one need to show *(C2)* from *(C1)*?)

---

### Bibliography

[Kun80] Kenneth Kunen: *Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs.* North Holland, 1980

Comment: This question extends (and improves) two questions previously asked at MSE. Both remained unanswered and I just deleted them. If you think this question is not good enough for MO, please migrate it to MSE. Thanks!

Comment: In order to show that C1 doesn't imply C3 you can take $\mathbb{Q}$ to be Cohen forcing and take $\mathbb{P}$ to be the lottery sum of $\mathbb{Q}$ and something which is not c.c.c. (for example the collapse $Col(\omega, \omega_1)$). Now clearly $\mathbb{Q}$ adds a generic for $\mathbb{P}$ but there is no complete embedding from $\mathbb{P}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ since by condition (ii) it would give you an uncountable antichain in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Yair: Why are you online?

Comment: @YairHayut: Thanks for your helpful comment. Two more questions: (1) Is $ \operatorname{RO}(\mathbb{Q}) $ also c.c.c. if $ \mathbb{Q} $ is c.c.c.? So does your example also show that *(C1) implies (C4)* is impossible? (2) What about *((C1) and (C2)) implies ((C3) or (C4))*?

Comment: To answer the first question in Justus87's second comment: Yes. If a dense subset of a poset is ccc then so is the whole poset.

Comment: A fact that I heard mentioned is that if $\mathbb Q$ adds a generic for $\mathbb P$, then there is some condition $p\in\mathbb P$ such that $\mathbb P$ below $p$ embeds into $\text{ro}(\mathbb Q)$. (Note that this avoids Yair's counterexample) Is there a simple proof of this?

Comment: An interesting counterexample to $(D4)\Rightarrow(D3)$ is due to Zapletal in *On the existence of a $\sigma$-closed dense subset* [MR2741884](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2741884). Zapletal shows that it is consistent to have two dense subsets $P$ and $Q$ of some poset such that $P$ is $\sigma$-closed but $Q$ has no $\sigma$-closed dense subset. It's an open question whether the existence of such $P$ and $Q$ is provable in ZFC.

Comment: C3 implies C2: Work with the boolean completions $RO( P)$ and $RO(Q)$ as computed in M. The complete embedding of $P$ into $Q$ extends to an injective homomorphism $i:RO(P )\to RO(Q)$ which $M$ models to be complete. Given $G$ $M$-generic for $P$, $i[G]$ generates a filter in $M[G]$ on the boolean algebra $RO(Q)^M$ as computed in $M$ which is still a boolean algebra in $M[G]$, though not a complete one. Let $J\in M[G]$ be the dual ideal of the filter generated by $i[G]$. In $M[G]$, $RO(Q)^M/J$ gives rise to a notion of forcing. Let now $H$ be $M[G]$-generic for this forcing to conclude.

Comment: In general in my eyes all these type of arguments are better understood looking not at complete embeddings but at complete homomorphisms (possibly non injective - see the comment of Victoria Gitman above) of the boolean completions. May be you can find some other informations on some of these questions in http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1714

Comment: @matteoviale: Thanks for your comments. In general, I agree that working with complete Boolean algebras has its benefits! However, one can prove ***(C3)* implies *(C2)*** explicitly using one of Kunen's exercises. (See the answer below.) Nevertheless, I think your solution is quite similar.

Comment: @VictoriaGitman: Thanks for the hint! I think this is the way to go, but I don't know the proof. Somebody has to know it!?!?

Comment: @Justus87: Joel Hamkins wrote a [blog post](http://jdh.hamkins.org/common-forcing-extension-via-different-forcing-notions/) with a proof two days ago because this fact came up in our discussion. I meant to make a comment about it and forgot.

Comment: @VictoriaGitman: Cool, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The following implications are either trivial or well known:**

*(D$ n $)* implies *(C$ n $)*: Trivial.

*(C3)* implies *(C1)*: Use $ G := i^{-1}[H] $. (See [Kun80, VII.7.5].)

*(C3)* implies *(C4)*: The composition of two complete embeddings is a complete embedding.

*(D3)* implies *(D1)*: Use $ G := i^{-1}[H] $. Then $ H = \{ q \in Q : \exists p \in G \ i(p) \leq q \} $. (See [Kun80, VII.7.11].)

*(D3)* implies *(D2)*: Use $ H := \{ q \in Q : \exists p \in G \ i(p) \leq q \} $. Then $ G = i^{-1}[H] $. (See [Kun80, VII.7.11].)

*(D3)* implies *(D4)*: The composition of two dense embeddings is a dense embedding.

---

Regarding ***(C1)* does not imply *(C3)*** and ***(C1)* does not imply *(C4)***:

Let $ \mathbb{Q} $ be the Cohen forcing and let $ \mathbb{P} $ be the lottery sum of $ \mathbb{Q} $ and $ \operatorname{Col}(\omega, \omega_1) $. Then *(C1)* clearly holds (use $ G := H $), but *(C3)* and *(C4)* do not hold since $ \mathbb{P} $ is not c.c.c. whereas $ \mathbb{Q} $ and hence $ \operatorname{RO}(\mathbb{Q}) $ satisfy the countable chain condition.

(See the comments of **Yair Hayut** and **Andreas Blass**.)

Also see [*A common forcing extension obtained via different forcing notions*](http://jdh.hamkins.org/common-forcing-extension-via-different-forcing-notions/) by J.D. Hamkins or [*Lemma 25.5*](http://books.google.com/books?id=pLxq0myANiEC&pg=PA267) in T. Jech's book *Set Theory* (1978 edition).

---

Regarding ***(C3)* implies *(C2)***:

Each $ H \subseteq Q $ which is $ \mathbb{Q} / G $-generic over $ M[G] $ is also $ \mathbb{Q} $-generic over $ M $, and
$$
G \in M[G][H]_{\mathbb{Q} / G} = M[H]_{\mathbb{Q}}.
$$

(See [Kun80, VII.Ex.D3] and [Kun80, VII.Ex.D4].)